# How to check whether the currently logged in user attributes are equal with another table attributes in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I check whether the currently logged in user's attributes(Users table) are equal with the other table (DietExercise table)  attributes, if they are equal display the corresponding diet plan.

Below is DietExercise firebase table

```
DietExercise
    -1
      -Age: 20
      -ArtheritisPatient: "yes"
      -BMI: "Overweight"
      -Chol_level: "High"
      -DiabetesPatient: "yes"
      -DietPlan: "Breakfast - Boiled Chickpea 1 cup, scraped coco..."
      -ExercisePlan: "Contact your doctor for exercise plans"
      -Gender: "Male"
      -HeartPatient: "yes"
```

Below is the Users firebase table

```
Users
    -0771212122
        ArthritisP: "no"
        BMI: "Overweight "
        CholesterolLevel: "High"
        DiabetesP: "yes"
        HeartP: "no"
        age: "32"
        name: "Siliya"
        password: ""
        phoneNumber: "0771212122"
```

Below is the code.

```
  public class dplanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            TextView a;
        
            private String parentDbName1 = "Users";
           private String parentDbName2 = "DietExercise";
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_dplan);
        
                a=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewD);    
        
        
                final DatabaseReference RootRef;
                RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        
                RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if(dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName1).child("age").equals(dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName2).child("Age"))) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName1).child("BMI").equals(dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName2).child("BMI"))) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName1).child("CholesterolLevel").equals(dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName2).child("Chol_level"))) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName1).child("DiabetesP").equals(dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName2).child("DiabetesPatient"))) {
                                        if (dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName1).child("HeartP").equals(dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName2).child("HeartPatient"))) {
                                                if (dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName1).child("ArthritisP").equals(dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName2).child("ArtheritisPatient"))) {
                                                    String diet=dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName2).child("DietPlan").getValue().toString();
                                                    a.setText(diet);
                                                }
        
                                                }
        
                                        }
        
                                    }
        
                                }
                                }
        
                                }
```

Comment: What are the exact attributes that you would like to know that are "equal"?

Comment: @AlexMamo Users(age, bmi, CholesterolLevel, DiabetetsP, HeartP, ArthritisP) == DietExercise (Age, BMI, Chol_level, DiabetesPatient, HeartPatient, ArtheritisPatient)

Comment: So you want to check if an object of type `Users` "is equal" to an object of type `DietExercise`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes I want to check a attribute in Users table "is equal" to an attributes in DietExercise table

Comment: Which particular one?

Comment: @AlexMamo  When a user is registering to the app user input their details. Those details are stored in the users table. I want to check the particular user details with the DietExercise table data. If they are equal I want to show the diet plan (DietExercise table) . Every data raw in the DietExercise table should be checked with the the current user details. If any of them are equal the corresponding diet plan should display. Hope you understand.